# PyQt Hide QDialogs Inside of QTreeWidget

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, qt4, pyqt

I have a QTreeWidget with QComboBoxes inside of it.  I would like to be able to hide the combo boxes.

I am getting the QComboBox out of the tree using the itemWidget function.  I have tried using setVisible(False) and hide() but neither work.  Can anyone explain why this is the case and possibly offer a soultion?

I suspect it has something to do with the QTreeWidget or the QTreeWidgetItems controlling the visibility of its widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the QComboBoxes inside a layout inside a QWidget, and placing the QWidget in the QTreeWidget?

Comment: This doesn't seem to do the trick.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @freakTheMightyin that case you may need to subclass QTreeWidget and change its paintEvent function